# Google Chrome Extension redirect URL

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need to redirect some specific URL to another specific URL.
For example, I want to redirect "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABCDefgHIJK" to "https://zymernation.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Internet-Access-Error-e1558967567821.jpg"

To do this, I've made a script where I can get current URL, but can not redirect URL.

I've got some code for this but they did not work perfectly.

Need expert guideline.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution:

**manifest.json**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "test",
"description": "google chrome  extension",
"version": "1.0",

"browser_action": {
 "default_icon": "icon.png"
},
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
"permissions": [
    "tabs"
 ]
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) { // listener for tab opens
if (changeInfo.status == 'loading') { // when the page is loading (you can do info.status === 'complete' but you will see the page for a second or two)
    if (tab.url === "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABCDefgHIJK") {
        chrome.tabs.query({ // change the tab url
            currentWindow: true,
            active: true
        }, function (tab) {
            chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {
                url: 'https://zymernation.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Internet-Access-Error-e1558967567821.jpg'
            });
        });
    }
}
})
```

Comment: Mr. Tomer Raitz, how to redirect it by title, for example I want to redirect the page if the title contains "Movie" word.

Comment: You can search in the string (title/ URL) if the word exists by `includes()` if so run the code. for example `tab.url.includes("Movie")`